# I have 3 divs in one row, how do I get the middle div comes first and first div comes in second and third div comes last in mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 divs in one row, how do I get the middle div comes first and first div comes in second and third div come last in mobile?

```
<div class="first">hello first</div>
<div class="middle">hello Middle</div>
<div class="last">hello last</div>

.first {float:left; width:33%;}

.middle {float:left; width:33%;}

.last {float:left; width:33%;}
```

Comment: This is not even Bootstrap? Are you planning on using bootstrap?

Comment: @Arjan Knol yes i am planning using bootstrap...

Comment: Are they also full width on larger screens?

Comment: @ZimSystem IN full width larger screen show hello first,hello middle, hello last & and in responsive hello middle come first then hello first then hello last

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bootstrap as per you question, there's also a way to specify div ordering on per breakpoint basis, using Bootstrap's pull/push classes. Assumed you set the right order as it should be on mobile, first:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="middle col-md-4 col-md-push-4 col-sm-4">hello middle</div>
  <div class="first col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-pull-4 ">hello first</div>
  <div class="last col-md-4 col-sm-4">hello last</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ximes/dw8n36jj/

See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering for more info/examples.

Answer (score 1):

- If you give `float:left` to all these divs, they will display
  respectively in the order they are written in your HTML.
- To make divs display in a one row you need to display them as
  `inline-block` because they are dispalyed as `block` by default.

**Solution:**

You just need to remove `float:left;` from `first` and `last` elements and use `display:inline-block` with all these divs, it will give you the expected results even on mobile.

**Demo:**

This is a sample working Demo:

```css
.first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

.middle {
  display: inline-block;
  ;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}

.last {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">hello first</div>
<div class="middle">hello Middle</div>
<div class="last">hello last</div>
```

Comment: @chsdk he un-accepted all our answers, mine got accepted twice

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the extra CSS to set the widths. Just use the Bootstrap grid and column ordering..

http://www.codeply.com/go/eMKtd3qzYU

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="middle col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">hello Middle</div>
        <div class="first col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">hello first</div>
        <div class="laste col-sm-4">hello last</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats a perfect methed

Comment: Thats a perfect methed to solve my problem Thanks @ZimSystem

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="first">hello first</div>
<div class="middle">hello Middle</div>
<div class="last">hello last</div>
.first {display:inline-block; width:33%;}
.middle {float:left; width:33%;}
.last {display:inline-block; width:33%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gaLo5s1o/

Comment: @GauravPanwar "work in responsive"? what do you mean?

Comment: @GauravPanwar it's working for me, as can be seen in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaLo5s1o/ "hello Middle" comes first, then "hello first", then "hello last", that's what you asked for, no?

Comment: Thanks Working Fine :)

Comment: @GauravPanwar you can't accept all 3 answers as the right one ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then use `col-sm-push-4` on second `div` and `col-sm-pull-4` on first `div`

Answer (score -1):

> Here is a sample code using flexbox approach .

```css
.parent{ display:flex; flex-direction:row;}
.parent div{ height:200px;width:33%;}
.first { background:red;}

.middle {  background:yellow;}

.last {  background:blue;}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .parent {
      flex-direction: row; 
    }
    .parent div{
      width:100%; 
    }
    .first {
      order: 2;
    }

    .second{
     order: 1;
    }
    .third{
    order:3}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="first">hello first</div>
<div class="middle">hello Middle</div>
<div class="last">hello last</div>

</div>
```